# How to add code from 2nd class to 1st class

Tags: java, android, google-maps

All code my app is in this class

```
    public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
            OnMapReadyCallback,
            GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
            GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
{
my_app
}
```

I found very important for my app code on stack, but this code is in other class:

```
public class GpsLocationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver implements LocationListener 
...

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
        if (intent.getAction().matches("android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED"))
        { 
            // react on GPS provider change action 
        }
}
```

I do not know how to add the code from Class 2 to 1. Help.

Comment: Since it is a broadcast reciever you need to register it first in the manifest before you can use that class. And if you are going to only listen for the location then just use the `LocationListener ` in your first class

Answer (score 0):

You can use an interface.

```
public class GpsLocationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver implements LocationListener 
...

private ReceiverListener mListener;

public GpsLocationReciever(Activity activity){(RecieverListener) mListener = activity;}

interface RecieverListener {
void onRecieveCallback();
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    if (intent.getAction().matches("android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED"))
    { 
        // react on GPS provider change action
        mListener.onRecieveCallback();
    }
}
```

And on your main activity (your 1st class!) add `implements GpsLocationReciever`

and override `onRecieveCallback` (on your 1st class!):

```
@override
public void onRecieveCallback(){
   //Here you code whatever you would be coding on onRecieve from your second class
}
```

Comment: but this is all in 2nd class and i want  all in 1st class

Comment: `implements GpsLocationReciever` and `onRecieveCallback()` are on the 1st class

Comment: "private ReceiverListener mListener;" i have error here